# wrong icons on desktop

Tags: .desktop

As a result of some misconfiguration, I had to redo a number of things in my Kubuntu 14.04 system.  I've pretty much fixed everything, but now I have a new problem: the icons visible on my desktop are the contents of my home directory, not the contents of ~/Desktop.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file and change the value of `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR`

e.g. `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR ="$HOME/Desktop"`